# jQuery ajax double encoding issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, urlencode

I am trying to send an ajax call to the server which reads input text from the user (it's Hebrew in utf-8 charset).
I use something like this:

```
my_url = some_url + textinput
my_url = encodeURI(my_url)
```

The problem that I see is that after the `encodeURI` function, the Hebrew part looks like that: `%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9F` (which is fine). I then use the jquery call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: search_url,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'json',
    error:errorData,
    success:getSearchResults
});
```

and I see that at the server it looks like it was encoded again such that each "%" sign is now %25 (the utf-8 representation of percent sign) and my Hebrew part looks like that:

`%25D7%259E%25D7%259C%25D7%2595%25D7%259F` (each "%" => %25)

I couldn't find any way to overcome this, I hope you can :-)

Cheeers,
Roy

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you're encoding the GET parameters in the actual url. Is there a reason not to just use the `data` attribute in your `.ajax()` options?

Comment: Also, is there a reason you have to encode it the first time? It looks like `.ajax()` might do it for you.

Comment: @nrabinowitz As for using the data attribute, well, I didn't try that yet and I probably will (do you have an example or shell I dig...?). As for your second remark, well, i tried this as well but it seems that just concatenating the hebrew part to the url wasn't encoded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option here is to use the `data` attribute in the `.ajax()` options. I've mocked up a version here: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/nmZra/1/

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/search_results/',
    data: { search: text },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: $.noop
});
```

There isn't a great way to get jQuery to show the actual URL being requested, but if you look in a console like Firebug, you can see the error message (because this is a bogus URL):

> GET http://fiddle.jshell.net/search_results/?search=%D7%91%D7%92%22%D7%A5+%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%99%D7%9D%3A+%D7%97%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%95+%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%99%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA+%D7%A2%D7%9D+%D7%94%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%A8 404 (NOT FOUND)

It looks like it's encoding the Hebrew text correctly, without the double-encoding issue you're having.